# AngularJs ng-repeat didn't updated after changing $scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have table with item list and modal window where i can change drug properties. When properties changed that drug have to remove from that list. But it's didn't remove.

Modal window:

```
 $modal.open({
    templateUrl:'app/interactions/partials/modals/resolveDrug.html',
    controller: 'DrugsListController',
    scope: $scope
}).result.then(function(data){
    var index = _.findIndex($scope.drugs, {_id: data._id});
    $scope.drugs.splice(index,1);
}
```

i think element didn't remove 'cause when i open modal window i create copy of my scope and then work with copy..

On that form i have refresh button that refresh all list.

```
 $scope.refresh= function() {
    $scope.drugs = UnresolvedDrugsService.query();
};
```

and it's didn't work too. I think it happens because i work with copy too.
Okey, i try to emit some event

```
$modal.open({
    templateUrl:'app/interactions/partials/modals/resolveDrug.html',
    controller: 'DrugsListController',
    scope: $scope
}).result.then(function(data){
    var index = _.findIndex($scope.drugs, {_id: data.data._id});

    $rootScope.$emit('refreshDrug', index);

}

$rootScope.$on('refreshDrug', function(index){
    $scope.drugs = [];
    $scope.drugs.splice(index,1);
   // $scope.drugs= UnresolvedDrugsService.query();
});
```

And it's not working.

Can you help me and describe what  i doing wrong, thx!

**UPD**
modal window html

```
<form role="form" name="resolveDrugForm"  ng-submit="saveResolvedDrug(drug) && $close(drug)">
   ........{some code, input's and label}......
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="{{'COMMON.SAVE' | translate}}"/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$dismiss()" >{{'COMMON.CANCEL' | translate}}</button>
```

code of ng-repeat

```
<tr ng-repeat="drug in drugs" ng-click="resolveDrug($index)">
            <td>{{drug.productName || drug.description }}</td>
            <td>{{drug.aiccode  }}</td>
</tr>
```

and all method of controller:

```
 $rootScope.$on('refreshDrug', function(index){
       // $scope.drugs = [];
        $scope.drugs.splice(index,1);
       // $scope.drugs= UnresolvedDrugsService.query();
    });


    $scope.drugs= UnresolvedDrugsService.query();

    $scope.refresh= function() {
        $scope.drugs= UnresolvedDrugsService.query();
    };
    $scope.spliceEl = function(data){
        var index = _.findIndex($scope.drugs, {_id: data._id});
        $scope.drugs.splice(index,1);
        return true;
    };
    $scope.saveResolvedDrug = function(drug){
        DrugsService.addResolvedDrug(drug).then(function(data){
            var index = _.findIndex($scope.drugs, {_id: data.data._id});
            if(data.data.ingredients && data.data.ingredients.length > 0){
                data.data.ingredients = JSON.parse(data.data.ingredients);
            }
            $scope.drugs.splice(index,1);
            return true;
        });
        return true;
    };

    $scope.resolveDrug=function(index){
        $scope.drug={};
        var drugs = $scope.drugs;
        $scope.drug=angular.copy($scope.drugs[index]);
        var scope=$scope;
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl:'app/interactions/partials/modals/resolveDrug.html',
            controller: 'DrugsListController',
            scope: $scope
        }).result.then(function(data){
                console.log($scope.drugs);
                var index = _.findIndex($scope.drugs, {_id: data._id});
                //$scope.drugs.splice(index,1);

                console.log($scope.drugs);
                $rootScope.$emit('refreshDrug', index);

            }, function(data){

            }).finally(function(data){
                $scope.refresh();
            });

    }
```

Comment: Is the code inside the callback executed when you close the modal? So is the line $scope.drugs.splice executed in any case? Can you confirm this with a console.log or similar?

Comment: @Darneas 
after splice in callback
`$modal.open({
..
            }).result.then(function(data){
                    console.log($scope.drugs);
                    var index = _.findIndex($scope.drugs, {_id: data._id});
                    $scope.drugs.splice(index,1);
                    console.log($scope.drugs);
                }
`
and console.log
`[f, f, $promise: Object, $resolved: true]
[f, $promise: Object, $resolved: true]`

Comment: Could you edit your answer and add more of your surrounding controller's code and perhaps the relevant parts of your HTML?

Comment: @Darneas done. At first i think that problem exist 'cause i use copy of $scope, but i didn't understand why didn't work with events..

Comment: Why do you set `drugs = []` and splice afterwards? If you do not want to use the event-based mechanism, you could try`$scope.$digest()` as your last instruction.

Comment: @Darneas event-based didn't work too.. and i didn't know why.
and about $scope.drugs=[] i forgot to comment it but it still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87372/discussion-between-handless-and-darneas).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know why it didn't works with events. But if saveDrug in modal result but sumbit form - work fine. 
Now code looks like

```
   $scope.resolveDrug=function(index){
        $scope.drug={};
        var drugs = $scope.drugs;
        $scope.drug=angular.copy($scope.drugs[index]);
        var scope=$scope;
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl:'app/interactions/partials/modals/resolveDrug.html',
            controller: 'DrugsListController',
            scope: scope,
            resolve: {
                drug: function () {
                    return $scope.drug;
                }
            }
        }).result.then(function(data){
            }, function(data){

            }).finally(function(data){

            });

    }
   $scope.saveResolvedDrug = function(drug){
        DrugsService.addResolvedDrug(drug).then(function(data){
            var index = _.findIndex($scope.drugs, {_id: data.data._id});
            if(data.data.ingredients && data.data.ingredients.length > 0){
                data.data.ingredients = JSON.parse(data.data.ingredients);
            }
            $scope.drugs.splice(index,1);
            return true;
        });
        return true;
    };
```